# Is there any shortcut way to navigate from a variable to its setter/getter method

Tags: eclipse, navigation, shortcut

In Eclipse we can easily create setter/getter method for any class variable. But I was wondering if there is any way to quickly navigate to the setter/getter method (once defined) from the variable (apart from <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! I found it just now (should have done more research before posting this query). It looks like if you select the variable and open the `Open Call Hierarchy` i.e. <kbd>CTRL+ALT+H</kbd> option you will get the methods.